# UIViewController subclass (mimics UITableViewController) doesn't get released

Tags: c#, ios, inheritance, memory-management, xamarin

I have subclassed `UIViewController`, which mimics `UITableViewController` == `HUDTableViewController`. Then I subclass from this subclassed view controller (`SomeViewController : HUDTableViewController`).

If I simulate a memory warning, `SomeViewController` doesn't get released. Here is the code of `HUDTableViewController`:

```
using System;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class HUDTableViewController : UIViewController, IUITableViewDataSource, IUITableViewDelegate, IDisposable, IUIScrollViewDelegate
    {
        private UIView parentView;
        private UITableView tableView;

        public UITableView TableView
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tableView;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tableView = value;
            }
        }

        public HUDTableViewController() : base()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            this.tableView = new UITableView();
            this.tableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            this.tableView.WeakDelegate = this;
            this.tableView.WeakDataSource = this;

            this.parentView = new UIView();
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            this.parentView.AddSubview(this.tableView);
            View = this.parentView;

            NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
            viewsDictionary["parent"] = this.parentView;
            viewsDictionary["tableView"] = this.tableView;

            this.parentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|[tableView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
            this.parentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|[tableView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
        }

        [Foundation.Export("numberOfSectionsInTableView:")]
        public virtual System.nint NumberOfSections(UIKit.UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public virtual System.nint RowsInSection(UIKit.UITableView tableview, System.nint section)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public virtual UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [Export("tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public virtual System.nfloat EstimatedHeight(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        }

        [Foundation.Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public virtual void RowSelected(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
        }

        [Export("tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public virtual System.nfloat GetHeightForRow(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 44.0f;
        }

        [Foundation.Export("tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:")]
        public virtual System.nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section)
        {
            return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        }

        [Foundation.Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
        public virtual UIKit.UIView GetViewForHeader(UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [Export("tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:")]
        public virtual string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        [Foundation.Export("tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public virtual void WillDisplay(UIKit.UITableView tableView, UIKit.UITableViewCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`tableView` should have a reference count of 2 (because of `AddSubView` and my property).

This is the main view controller, which instantiates `SomeViewController`:

```
public class MasterViewContainer : UIViewController
{
    private bool hasSetupHandlersAndEvents = false;
    // ...

    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        if (!hasSetupHandlersAndEvents) {
            if (listButton != null) {
                listButton.Clicked += listButton_Clicked;
            }
            hasSetupHandlersAndEvents = true;
        }
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);

        if (hasSetupHandlersAndEvents) {
            if (listButton != null) {
                listButton.Clicked -= listButton_Clicked;
            }
            hasSetupHandlersAndEvents = false;
        }
    }

    private void listButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args){
        SomeViewController viewController = new SomeViewController();
        viewController.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
        NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, false);
    }
}
```

As you can see `SomeViewController` has a reference to `MasterViewContainer`, because of `SomeEventHandler`.

`SomeViewController` is released if I use

```
public class SomeViewController : UITableViewController
```

, but it isn't released if I use

```
public class SomeViewController : HUDTableViewController
```

The `Dispose` method is never called. I don't see a reference cycle. Where do I have to release something? What I'm missing?

**Try 1:**

This is the only solution, which comes to my mind. I use a field (class variable) where I hold the reference to `SomeViewController`. In `DidReceiveMemoryWarning` I manually release/dispose it. When I want to access the field, I check if it has been initialised before. If not I initialise it when needed.

```
public class MasterViewContainer : UIViewController
{
    private SomeViewController viewController;

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        if (this.viewController != null)
        {
            this.viewController.SomeEvent -= SomeEventHandler;
            this.viewController.Dispose();
            this.viewController = null;
        }
    }

    private void listButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args){
        if (this.viewController == null)
        {
            this.viewController = new SomeViewController();
            this.viewController.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
        }

        NavigationController.PushViewController(this.viewController, false);
    }
```

But this solution isn't perfect. The dispose is also called when the view is currently on screen. So it is very likely to have malfunctions.

**Bounty:**

I'd like to have a solution, which explains the memory management issue. Why it doesn't get released? What has to change to get it released (without doing stuff like in my try). It should behave like `UITableViewController`.

**Try 2:**

Now I tried to override the `Dispose(bool disposing)` of `HUDTableViewController`:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(!this.disposed)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
           this.tableView.RemoveFromSuperview();
           this.tableView.Dispose();
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Neither this `Dispose` method of `HUDTableViewController` nor the `Dispose` method of `SomeViewController` is called.

Comment: What do you need `parentView` for? There's already a root view for controller, which is guaranteed to be created in `ViewDidLoad`. So instead of adding tableView as its subview, you *replace* it with your `parentView`. The original view might persist in hierarchy and reference the controller, so the latter is not released.

Comment: I use this `HUDTableViewController` because I want to center a loading spinner on it. So I could use this class without further effort. For the centering I introduced the `parentView`, because `View` (which is `UITableView`) doesn't work and I had issues if I tried to use the parent of `UITableView`. Do I have some options releasing the reference somehow? Or perhaps you have a better idea centering a view in a `UITableView`.

Comment: Shouldn't you explicitely implement the Dispose() method?

Comment: @FredM: I can if I have something to dispose. The question is what should I dispose/release? Also in my project the `Dispose()` is never called automatically. So I can only call `Dispose()` manually. The default `UITableViewController` doesn't need to call `Dispose()` manually.

Comment: You could try this: https://lostechies.com/chrispatterson/2012/11/29/idisposable-done-right/

Comment: @FredM: Seems to be very similar to what [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) proposes. Nevertheless I'll read it more thoroughly. The question in the moment is what should I dispose? What I can dispose is to remove the subview from `parentView`. Do you think implementing `Dispose()` as described in your link will help? I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'd implement the Dispose method to, first, check that is called as expected, and second, call the base version to make sure it is called as well...

Comment: @FredM: I tried it as stated in the link you posted. Still the `Dispose` method isn't called.

Comment: And if you try with "this.viewController.Dispose(true)" to make sure the proper overload is called?

Comment: @FredM: You mean manually disposing? That is what I'm doing in try 1 and currently in my project respectively. Here the parent of `SomeViewController` is disposing `SomeViewController`. This is working without overwriting `Dispose(bool)`. The default `UITableViewController` doesn't need to be disposed manually. I also want this behavior (and also no reference cycle). Then I don't have to think about releasing manually.

Answer (score 0):

Call super if you are wanting your parent view to also call the same function handle your management from there. Depending on the arrangement you wouldn't need to do any other manual disposing.

```
public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
{
    // If you want the superclass to fire the function first call super first
    // and vice versa. 
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning();
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
```